# Pause and Resume recording a video is not continue

Tags: android, react-native, camera, record, expo

I am building a camera app (android target) with expo.
My problem is during recording a video. I look forward after pause and resume a video It should record continue but it's freezed after I save my record video.

This is my code:

```
if (!this.state.isStartRecordVideo) {
        this.props.pauseRecordVideo();
}
else {
        this.props.resumeRecordVideo();
}
```

`startRecordVideo` method to start a record video:

```
async startRecordVideo() {
    let video = await this.camera.recordAsync({ quality: '1080' });
    await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(video.uri, 'video');
}
```

`stopRecordVideo` method to stop and save a record video (return a promise in `startRecordVideo` method)

```
async stopRecordVideo() {
    await this.camera.stopRecording();
}
```

`FooterCamera` is a component which contain `pausePreview` and `resumePreview`

```
<FooterCamera
    ref={(footer) => this.footer_camera = footer}
    imageUri={this.state.imageUri}
    takePicture={(timer, quality) => this.takePicture(timer, quality)}
    startRecordVideo={() => this.startRecordVideo()}
    stopRecordVideo={() => this.stopRecordVideo()}
    pauseRecordVideo={() => this.camera.pausePreview()}
    resumeRecordVideo={() => this.camera.resumePreview()}
    stopCountDownAnimate={() => this.stopCountDownAnimate()}
/>
```

1. expo version: 2.1.3
2. Device: android

Comment: please paste your `startRecordVideo()` Method

Comment: async startRecordVideo() {
    let video = await this.camera.recordAsync({ quality: '1080' });
    await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(video.uri, 'video');
  }

Hi @Ali startRecordVideo is just basic like it

Comment: you just call this method where you save your video.

Comment: my video is saved after I stop recording (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera#stoprecording)

Comment: @Ali I updated my question. I hope you can give me a solution for my problem.

Comment: Hi, Any idea how we can pasue recording and resume it?

Answer (score 0):

`pausePreview` function works to pause recording? I don't think so... It just pauses "preview", not recording. Please double check about `pausePreview()` and `resumePreview()` function in reference.